# Is it possible to pass data to custom form fields files from a loaded form?

Tags: joomla-3.x, fields

In my custom component, under the models folder, is the fields folder which contains the php files for dropdown lists in the .xml by defining its type.

For example, I have a schema.php file in the fields folder, I should specify the type to "schema" correct?

```
  <field name="report_id" type="schema" class="inputbox"
        label="COM_SUBSCRIPTION_FORM_LBL_FIELDS_REPORTID"
        description="COM_SUBSCRIPTION_FORM_DESC_FIELDS_REPORTID" 
        table = "#__reports_"  key_field="ID" value_field="TITLE" 
   />
```

When the page reloads, it again calls the schema.php to populate the form field which is of type schema.

I have a dropdown list in my form, which is a custom field type. My form also has a report_Id.

Now I want to use the report_Id as my parameter to filter the content of my dropdown list when the page of the edit form loads.

**UPDATE #1:**

I have tried using this code in the getInput function of the schema.php file:

```
$data= JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('jform', array(), 'array');
```

but it does not return the form together with its inputs when I use var_dump.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the `$_POST` inside your field class like:

```
$input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
```

[See](https://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput) the reference for `JInput`.

Though it feels like a bad design I do not see any other option how to pass the data there.

Also you can access the data of your current form in your field class like this:

```
$formData = $this->form->getData();
```

You will get a `Registry` object containing the data.

If you want to update your dropdown list based on your report_Id dynamically then you will need some JS skills.

Comment: what do you mean use the $_POST then you have provided a syntax for JInput?

Comment: If you follow the reference I gave you will find the answer to your question.

Comment: please see the update in my post.

Comment: May be your question is slightly wrong... Do you want to make some kind of input field which depends on the same form data? Because it is not so clear - you post your form (reload the same page?) and then you somehow get the form data again on the same page.

Comment: I apologize if I asked the wrong question, let me explain further:
I have a dropdown list in my form, which is a custom field type. My form also has a report_Id. Now i want to use the report_Id as my parameter to filter the content of my dropdown list when the page of the edit form loads.

Comment: Ok see my updated question.

Comment: thank you very much for that $this->form->getData() it is exactly what I needed!